# Consider group of permutation matrices and write out elements isomorphic to the group and exhibit it

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the group of permutation matrices $G =\{I_3, P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5\}$
For $n=3$ the permutation matrices are $I_3$ and the five matrices are:

\begin{equation*}
P_1 = [1,0,0;0,0,1;0,1,0] \\
P_2 = [0,1,0;1,0,0;0,0,1] \\
P_3 = [0,1,0;0,0,1;1,0,0] \\
P_4 = [0,0,1;0,1,0;1,0,0] \\
P_5 = [0,0,1;1,0,0;0,1,0]
\end{equation*}

Write out the elements of a group of permutations that is isomorphic to $G$, and exhibit an isomorphism from $G$ to this group!

I think it has to do with Cayley's Theorem.
With $f_a:G\to G$ defined by $f_a(x) = ax$ for each $a$ that exists in $G$...

I thought about making a table, but realize I don't know how to since I am dealing with matrices.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Look at the result of multiplying each of those matrices by the vector $(1,2,3)^T$.

Comment: Oh ok so P1=[132]  P2=[213]  P3=[231] P4=[321]  P5=[312]

Comment: SO now... Isomorphism would be the mapping of G->G' ?

Comment: Well, you have to check that it's an homomorphism.

Comment: Multiplying each of those by the vector did not come out to the isomorphisms...

Comment: check out how i solved this problem... this one i then solved similar

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/find-elements-of-group-permutation-that-is-isomorphic-to-u14